# How to Calculate Bill Total JS

Tags: javascript

I need to write a function called "calculateBillTotal".

Given the pre tax and pre tip amount of a meal, "calculateBillTotal" returns the total amount due after tax and tip.

Notes:
* Assume that sales tax is 9.5% and tip is 15%.
* Do NOT tip on the sales tax, only on the pre tip amount.

Here's my code:

```
function calculateBillTotal(preTaxAndTipAmount) {
  preTaxAndTipAmount - 9.5 + 15;

  return preTaxAndTipAmount;
}

var output = calculateBillTotal(20);
console.log(output); // --> it must be 24.9 but its return 20 instead.
```

Comment: Your statement `preTaxAndTipAmount - 9.5 + 15;` does the calculation but throws away the result, because it is not being assigned to anything. The next line `return preTaxAndTipAmount;` returns exactly the same amount that was passed in to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to figure out the math. Also, introducing temporary helper variables increases readability.

> Assume that sales tax is 9.5% and tip is 15%.

- 9.5% of the `preTaxAndTipAmount` is `preTaxAndTipAmount * 9.5 / 100` or simply `preTaxAndTipAmount * 0.095`.
- 15% of the `preTaxAndTipAmount` is then `preTaxAndTipAmount * 0.150`.

```js
function calculateBillTotal(preTaxAndTipAmount) {
  var tax = preTaxAndTipAmount * 0.095;
  var tip = preTaxAndTipAmount * 0.150;
  
  return preTaxAndTipAmount + tax + tip;
}

console.log(calculateBillTotal(20)); // 24.9
```

Comment: yeah may I know the math behind the 0.095 and 0.150?

Comment: @JimCarter See my edit. Don't hesitate to ask if it is still unclear.

Comment: @Serginho I don't think this question would be well received on math.stackexchange.com, it fits well here.

Comment: Acrualky the user has two questions, one abount maths, an another about coding.

Comment: @Serginho and? Shall he ask on math.stackexchange for how to apply percentages? This is clearly a beginner question with no use to other readers than OP, no need to split & distribute it over multiple sites. That's just my opinion though.

Answer (score 0):

Come on! You are returning the same variable.

```
function calculateBillTotal(preTaxAndTipAmount) {
  var total = preTaxAndTipAmount - 9.5 + 15;
  return total;
}
```

And the result is 25.5, not 24.9.

Comment: Nope the answer should be 24.9 there must be something wrong with your equation.

Comment: I'm solving your coding problem, not your real problem, that's not the goal of this forum. Maybe you have to ask here: https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Serginho this isn't a forum... it's a Q&A site :-)

Comment: It's a Q&A about coding, not Maths